# Magento 2.4 Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to upgrade my Magento 2.3 store to 2.4. In trying to do so, when I try to run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` I receive the following error: `Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster`

Here is what I have so far.

I am running nginx, here is the config file:

```
upstream panam_backend {
   server   php74:9000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name panam.localhost;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/panam.localhost;

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate /var/www/html/panam.localhost/key/panam.localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/html/panam.localhost/key/panam.localhost.key;

    root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

    index index.php;
    autoindex off;
    charset UTF-8;
    error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;
    #add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";

    # PHP entry point for setup application
    location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
        root $MAGE_ROOT;
        location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
            fastcgi_pass   panam_backend;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }
    }

    # PHP entry point for update application
    location ~* ^/update($|/) {
        root $MAGE_ROOT;

        location ~ ^/update/index.php {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass   panam_backend;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # Deny everything but index.php
        location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /pub/ {
        location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
            deny all;
        }
        alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }

    location /static/ {
        # Uncomment the following line in production mode
        # expires max;

        # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
        location ~ ^/static/version {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
        }

        location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires +1y;

            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
            }
        }
        location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires    off;

            if (!-f $request_filename) {
               rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
            }
        }
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }

    location /media/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;

        location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires +1y;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
        }
        location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires    off;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
        }
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }

    location /media/customer/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location /media/downloadable/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location /media/import/ {
        deny all;
    }

    # PHP entry point for main application
    location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   panam_backend;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;

    }

    location /_cluster/health {
          proxy_pass http://192.168.77.75:9250/_cluster/health;
       }

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
        text/plain
        text/css
        text/js
        text/xml
        text/javascript
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/xml+rss
        image/svg+xml;
    gzip_vary on;

    # Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
    location ~* (\.php$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
        deny all;
    }

}
#
## Optional override of deployment mode. We recommend you use the
## command 'bin/magento deploy:mode:set' to switch modes instead.
##
## set $MAGE_MODE default; # or production or developer
##
## If you set MAGE_MODE in server config, you must pass the variable into the
## PHP entry point blocks, which are indicated below. You can pass
## it in using:
##
## fastcgi_param  MAGE_MODE $MAGE_MODE;
##
## In production mode, you should uncomment the 'expires' directive in the /static/ location block
```

Here is the env.php file:

```
<?php
return [
    'cache_types' => [
        'config' => 1,
        'layout' => 1,
        'block_html' => 1,
        'collections' => 1,
        'reflection' => 1,
        'db_ddl' => 1,
        'eav' => 1,
        'customer_notification' => 1,
        'target_rule' => 1,
        'full_page' => 1,
        'config_integration' => 1,
        'config_integration_api' => 1,
        'translate' => 1,
        'config_webservice' => 1,
        'compiled_config' => 1,
        'vertex' => 1,
        'google_product' => 0
    ],
    'db' => [
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'dbname' => 'panam',
                'host' => 'db',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => '',
                'model' => 'mysql4',
                'engine' => 'innodb',
                'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
                'active' => '1',
                'profiler' => '1'
            ]
        ],
        'table_prefix' => ''
    ],
    'cache' => [
        'frontend' => [
            'default' => [
                'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
                'backend_options' => [
                    'server' => 'redis',
                    'database' => '0',
                    'port' => '6379'
                ]
            ],
            'page_cache' => [
                'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
                'backend_options' => [
                    'server' => 'redis',
                    'port' => '6379',
                    'database' => '1',
                    'compress_data' => '0'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer',
    'backend' => [
        'frontName' => 'admin'
    ],
    'crypt' => [
        'key' => 'abfd843e41c08030189ad4ebaf1191f0'
    ],
    'resource' => [
        'default_setup' => [
            'connection' => 'default'
        ]
    ],
    'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
    'session' => [
        'save' => 'redis',
        'redis' => [
            'host' => 'redis',
            'port' => '6379',
            'password' => '',
            'timeout' => '2.5',
            'persistent_identifier' => '',
            'database' => '2',
            'compression_threshold' => '2048',
            'compression_library' => 'gzip',
            'log_level' => '1',
            'max_concurrency' => '6',
            'break_after_frontend' => '5',
            'break_after_adminhtml' => '30',
            'first_lifetime' => '600',
            'bot_first_lifetime' => '60',
            'bot_lifetime' => '7200',
            'disable_locking' => '0',
            'min_lifetime' => '60',
            'max_lifetime' => '2592000'
        ]
    ],
    'install' => [
        'date' => 'Fri, 06 Apr 2018 22:04:26 +0000'
    ],
    'system' => [
        'default' => [
            'dev' => [
                'debug' => [
                    'debug_logging' => '0'
                ]
            ],
            'smile_elasticsuite_core_base_settings' => [
                'es_client' => [
                    'servers' => '192.168.77.75:9250',
                    'enable_https_mode' => '0',
                    'enable_http_auth' => '0',
                    'http_auth_user' => '',
                    'http_auth_pwd' => ''
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Here is output of `curl -XGET 'http://192.168.77.75:9250'` on the host computer:

```
{
  "name" : "ebrownserver",
  "cluster_name" : "7.6",
  "cluster_uuid" : "wWppBNI9SR29XtyhIZ-LnQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.6.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "ef48eb35cf30adf4db14086e8aabd07ef6fb113f",
    "build_date" : "2020-03-26T06:34:37.794943Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.4.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I've restarted nginx and elasticsearch many times, but it didn't help.

Also, as far as my configuration goes, nginx is setup on the host computer while elasticsearch is on a separate server on the network. I don't know if that changes anything, but that's how it's setup right now.

Also, elasticsearch used to be connected to a docker container on the host computer before it started causing a bunch of problems. The docker container had a different ip address than the one that is currently being used, so maybe a caching issue where it's trying to use the old ip address is occurring? Not sure, just throwing it out there.

Let me know if you need anymore information.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced this issue while upgrading my set on magento2.4.2. Trick here is to disable Elastic Search for a while and use php bin/magento commands easily. Here is the command to disable Elastic search:

```
php bin/magento module:disable {Magento_Elasticsearch,Magento_InventoryElasticsearch,Magento_Elasticsearch6,Magento_Elasticsearch7}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running elasticsearch in a separate container then localhost is the wrong hostname, you need to use the hostname of the ES container.